# Vaadin Spring (Vaadin 8) Not Found Any Pagination Components

Tags: java, spring, pagination, vaadin, vaadin8

I'm using Vaadin Spring (Vaadin 8) and looking for a nice pagination component.

I found this

https://vaadin.com/directory/component/pagination

,but I thought that it's not work even I followed its doc. There is no Table class for that pagination.

I also went to another Stackoverflow posts, they suggested about PagedTable

(https://vaadin.com/directory/component/pagedtable) (Vaadin 7)

and Vaadin 8 (https://vaadin.com/directory/component/gridextensionpack-add-on)

It involves with PagedContainer and there is still no PagedContainer in my Vaadin 8

What should I do now?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you give [this code](https://github.com/tsuoanttila/GridExtensionPack#getting-started) a try? it shows how to use the `PagedContainer `.

Comment: Already, No class PagedContainer

Comment: Maybe this link is helpful: https://vaadin.com/blog/lazy-loading-with-vaadin-8

Answer (score 1):

You can [use](https://github.com/tsuoanttila/GridExtensionPack/blob/master/GridExtensionPack/src/main/java/org/vaadin/teemusa/gridextensions/paging/PagedDataProvider.java) `PagedDataProvider` instead, it has been renamed since Vaadin 8 does not use containers anymore. Seems like a bug in the add-on documentation.

I've already [proposed](https://github.com/tsuoanttila/GridExtensionPack/pull/24/files) a documentation update, so you can track it.